# how can i draw arabic string above image in flutter (image processing)?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, image-processing

im using flutter image package to draw string above an image, by using drawstring() function , it work successfully when the input string is in english , but when the input string is in arabic it wasn't appear in the output image
this is the link of image package
https://pub.dev/packages/image
this is the code function to draw string at x and y point within image

```
Image.drawString(image!, Image.arial_24, 300, 300, "string to draw",color: Colors.black.value);
```

this line work successfully and draw the string at points x=300 and y=300,
but if we change the language to arabic it wasn't appear